# Powershell skip element in array, if it blank

Tags: powershell, jenkins, conditional-statements

I have a powershell script, where I receive names of elements as a variables from Jenkins:

```
$IISarray = @("$ENV:Cashier_NAME", "$ENV:Terminal_NAME", "$ENV:Content_Manager_NAME", "$ENV:Kiosk_BO_NAME")

foreach ($string in $IISarray){
"some code goes here"
}
```

Sometimes random elements can be blank. How can I add a check to see if the current element in array is blank, skip it and go to next element?

Comment: How about this? if ($varibalename -eq $null) { Write-Host "variable is null" }

Comment: `$IISarray | where-Object {$_} | Foreach-Object {...`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's easiest to **use `-ne ''` to created a filtered copy of the array that excludes empty entries**, courtesy of the ability of many PowerShell operators to act as a *filter* with an array-valued LHS.

Note: I'm assuming you mean to **filter out *empty strings***, not also *blank* (all-whitespace) ones, given that undefined environment variables expand to an *empty* string.

```
# Sample array with empty elements.
# Note: No need for @(...), unless there's just *one* element.
$IISarray = "foo", "", "bar", "baz", ""

# Note the `-ne ''`, which filters out empty elements.
foreach ($string in $IISarray -ne ''){
   $string # echo
}
```

The above yields:

```
foo
bar
baz
```

---

[soundstripe's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53286480/45375) offers a `Where-Object` solution, which potentially provides added flexibility via the ability to specify an arbitrary filter script block, but the use of a pipeline is a bit heavy-handed for this use case.
Fortunately, **PSv4+** offers the **`.Where()` collection *method***, which performs noticeably better.

Let me demonstrate it with **a solution that also rules out *blank* (all-whitespace) elements**:

```sh
# Note the all-whitespace element, which we want to ignore too.
PS> ("foo", "   ", "bar", "baz", "").Where({ $_.Trim() })
foo
bar
baz
```

Similar to the `Where-Object` cmdlet, you pass a *script block* to the `.Where()` method, inside of which the automatic `$_` variable represents the input element at hand.

The `.Trim()` method trims leading and trailing whitespace from a string and returns the result.
An all-whitespace string therefore results in the *empty* string.

In a Boolean context (as the `.Where()` method script block implicitly is), the *empty* string evaluates to `$false`, whereas any non-empty string is `$true`.
You can choose to be explicit, however (`$_.Trim() -ne ''`), or even use a .NET method (`[string]::IsNullOrWhiteSpace($_)`).

Answer (score 3):

You can use [`Where-Object`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/where-object) to filter out null or empty values. It is very commonly used, so  `?` is shorthand for `Where-Object`.

```
$IISarray = @("$ENV:Cashier_NAME", "$ENV:Terminal_NAME", "$ENV:Content_Manager_NAME", "$ENV:Kiosk_BO_NAME")

foreach ($string in ($IISarray | ? {$_})){
"some code goes here"
}
```

The `$_` is an automatic variable representing each incoming object in the pipeline. Both `$null` and the empty string `''` are falsy in Powershell, so only non-null values with length > 0 will be passed in to your for loop.

Answer (score 2):

```
# you can skip the `@` and brackets as well as the quotation marks
$IISarray = $ENV:Cashier_NAME, $ENV:Terminal_NAME, $ENV:Content_Manager_NAME, $ENV:Kiosk_BO_NAME

foreach($String in $IISarray) {
    # trim the strings and check the length
    if($String.Trim().Length -gt 0) {
        "some code goes here"
    }
}
```